# Why does loading the System assembly work in the F# Repl, but not in compiled code?

Tags: .net, reflection, f#

```
let system = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("System")
()
```

This works for me in the Repl, but not when compiled. Any idea why?

On compiled, I get the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Added the requested info.

Comment: I don't know why the exception is thrown but you could try this alternative: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof<System.String>)`

Comment: The [method's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) says that it needs to take the long assembly name, e.g. `"system, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"`

Comment: Good catch. I guess that just leaves explaining why it works in the Repl.

Comment: It works in REPL, because there this assembly is already loaded.